Field not being caught?
All of the fields except for Full_name is being caught when I try to POST or PUT.  Can you help?
Here's my Models and DTOs.
public class AbilityScore : BaseEntity
{
    public string Desc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Full_name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Index { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Url { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public record struct AbilityScoreCreateRequest(
    string Index,
    string Name,
    string Full_name,
    string Desc,
    string Url
    );

public record struct AbilityScoreResponse(
    int Id,
    string Index,
    string Name,
    string Full_name,
    string Desc,
    string Url
    );

public record struct AbilityScoreUpdateRequest(
    string Index,
    string Name,
    string Full_name,
    string Desc,
    string Url
    );

Here are my Services
public interface IAbilityScoreService
{
    Task<List<AbilityScoreResponse>> Create(AbilityScoreCreateRequest request);
    Task<List<AbilityScoreResponse>?> Update(int id, AbilityScoreUpdateRequest request);
}

public class AbilityScoreService : IAbilityScoreService
{
    private readonly IAbilityScoreRepository _abilityScoreRepository;

    public AbilityScoreService(IAbilityScoreRepository abilityScoreRepository)
    {
        _abilityScoreRepository = abilityScoreRepository;
    }

public async Task<List<AbilityScoreResponse>> Create(AbilityScoreCreateRequest request)
{
    TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    request.Full_name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(request.Full_name);
    request.Index = request.Index.ToLower();
    request.Name = request.Index.ToUpper();
    request.Url = $"/api/ability-scores/{request.Index}";

    var newObject = request.Adapt<AbilityScore>();
    var result = await _abilityScoreRepository.Create(newObject);
    return result.Adapt<List<AbilityScoreResponse>>();
}

public async Task<List<AbilityScoreResponse>?> Update(int id, AbilityScoreUpdateRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        request.Full_name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(request.Full_name);
        request.Index = request.Index.ToLower();
        request.Name = request.Index.ToUpper();
        request.Url = $"/api/ability-scores/{request.Index}";

        var updatedObject = request.Adapt<AbilityScore>();
        var result = await _abilityScoreRepository.Update(id, updatedObject);
        return result.Adapt<List<AbilityScoreResponse>>();
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

Let me know if you need more to help me diagnose.
Thanks!
